# Opening iPhone Map into our iPhone App as a one of View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, ios4, mkmapview

In My Application I Want use Native iPhone Application. For this purpose i get the code as below

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"]];
```

It is Working Fine. But it will come outs from the My App. I want Show this is as one of my screens such like We opening Camera in Our apps as a Screen. Similarly i want to show iPhone Native App as a one of my View in My Application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show another app as a direct view in your application.  Instead you'll need to add the MKMapKit framework to your project, make a new UIViewController in your project and in Interface Builder add in the MapKit UI element.  You can find tutorials online on how to use MapKit in your app to load specific areas on the map and do really neat things with it.

**EDIT:**
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Comment: But MKMAPVIew Can not invoke iPhone Native Map application ? I need to access Native iPhone App As a View in My application as like camera we are using in iPhone apps.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible.  You can either link OUTSIDE your application and go to another application (i.e. - Maps app) or you can embed the MapKit UI element in a custom view of your own and program what you need to do with it.

Comment: But it is done in other applications Like StarBucks iPhone App    http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/starbucks/id331177714?mt=8

Comment: Nope that's the way I explained you could do it.  Make your own view controller, add in the MKMapKit UI element from interface builder and access it programmatically.  Great tutorial is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MKMapView if you want a native map.

If you want to pass it a location like that you will also need to do some geocoding. Apple provide all of these API's but it isn't one line of code!

Comment: But MKMAPVIew Can not invoke iPhone Native Map application ? I need to access Native iPhone App As a View in My application as like camera we are using in iPhone apps.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you dont want to use `MKMapKit` as you didn't mentioned. If you want to show a web page in your app with request URL then you can do it with `UIWebView`.

You can load your request URL in web view as :-

```
NSString * urlStr = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London" ;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

(2) **i want to show iPhone Native App as a one of my View in My Application**

For that you can NOT.